# How to get first n elements in an array in Hive

Tags: hive

I use split function to create an array in Hive, how can I get the first n elements from the array, and I want to go through the sub-array

code example

```
select col1 from table
where split(col2, ',')[0:5]
```

'[0:5]'looks likes python style, but it doesn't work here.

Comment: what exactly do you intend to do with the n elements? you want each element in a separated row or a separated column?

Comment: I want them in a separated row, and I want to statistic the ratio of some value in the first n elements. Suppose I have row format like "abc#1,def#2,hij#3"... now, I want to know what's the ratio of #1 or #2 in the first three elements.

Comment: posted it as an answer..

Comment: Ovbiously, you're not qualified to select the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a tricky one.
First grab the brickhouse jar from [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse)
Then add it to Hive : `add jar /path/to/jars/brickhouse-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;`

Now create the two functions we will be usings :

`CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION array_index AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.ArrayIndexUDF';`
`CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION numeric_range AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.NumericRange';`

The query will be :

`select a,
        n as array_index,
        array_index(split(a,','),n) as value_from_Array 
 from ( select  "abc#1,def#2,hij#3" a from dual union all 
        select  "abc#1,def#2,hij#3,zzz#4" a from dual) t1 
 lateral view numeric_range( length(a)-length(regexp_replace(a,',',''))+1 ) n1 as n`

**Explained** :
`select  "abc#1,def#2,hij#3" a from dual union all 
        select  "abc#1,def#2,hij#3,zzz#4" a from dual`

Is just selecting some test data, in your case replace this with your table name.

`lateral view numeric_range( length(a)-length(regexp_replace(a,',',''))+1 ) n1 as n`

numeric_range is a UDTF that returns a table for a given range, in this case, i asked for a range between 0 (default) and the number of elements in string (calculated as the number of commas + 1)
This way, each row will be multiplied by the number of elements in the given column.

`array_index(split(a,','),n)`

This is exactly like using `split(a,',')[n]` but hive doesn't support it.
So we get the n-th element for each duplicated row of the initial string resulting in :

`abc#1,def#2,hij#3,zzz#4   0    abc#1
abc#1,def#2,hij#3,zzz#4    1    def#2
abc#1,def#2,hij#3,zzz#4    2    hij#3
abc#1,def#2,hij#3,zzz#4    3    zzz#4
abc#1,def#2,hij#3          0    abc#1
abc#1,def#2,hij#3          1    def#2
abc#1,def#2,hij#3          2    hij#3`

If you really want a specific number of elements (say 5) then just use :
`lateral view numeric_range(5 ) n1 as n`

Answer (score 3):

This is a much simpler way of doing it.  There is a UDF [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/TruncateArrayUDF.java) called `TruncateArrayUDF.java`that can do what you are asking.  Just clone the [repo](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) from the main page and build the jar with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).

**Example Data:**

```
|       col1         |
----------------------
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7
  11,12,13,14,15,16,17
```

**Query:**

```
add jar /complete/path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
create temporary function trunc as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.TruncateArrayUDF';

select pos
      ,newcol
from (
      select trunc(split(col1, '\\,'), 5) as p
      from table
     ) x
lateral view posexplode(p) explodetable as pos, newcol
```

**Output:**

```
  pos  |  newcol  |
-------------------
  0         1
  1         2
  2         3
  3         4
  4         5
  0         11
  1         12
  2         13
  3         14
  4         15
```

Comment: Yes, what Dimamesh does will technically work, but 'truncate_array' was made specifically for this use-case.

Brickhouse is available at http://github.com/klout/brickhouse .

Comment: @JeromeBanks Thanks for all the UDFs.  I use them everyday.  great stuff.

Comment: Can you give me an solution without using UDFs?

Comment: Good solution, wasn't aware of the `TruncateArray` UDF. Also `posexplode` is available only from hive 0.13.

Comment: The question wasn't 'How to get first n elements in an array in Hive without using a UDF', it was just 'How to get the first n elements in an array in Hive'