# how to use Posexplode function in hive

Tags: bash, hadoop

I am using `posexplode` to split single to multiple records in hive. 
Along with multiple records as output i need to generate sequence number for each row.

`col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4` are defined as string because rarely we get alpha data as well.

```
col1 | col2| col3 | col4 
---------------------------
  7  |  9  |  A   |  3
  5  |  6  |  9

Seq | Col
----------
 1  |  7
 2  |  9
 3  |  A
 4  |  3
 1  |  5
 2  |  6
 3  |  9
```

I am using below mentioned query but I am getting error

> `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token (`

My query is :

```
SELECT  
    seq, col  
FROM 
  (SELECT  array(  col1, col2 , col3,col4) as arr_r FROM srctable ) arrayrec
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(arrayrec) EXPLODED_rec as seq, col
```

How can this be resolved

I am able to run successfully this query :

```
SELECT  col  FROM 
(SELECT  array(  col1, col2 , col3,col4) 
as arr_r FROM srctable ) arrayrec
LATERAL VIEW explode(arrayrec) EXPLODED_rec as col
```

Which produces below output

```
  Col
 -----
   7
   9
   A
   3
   5
   6
   9
```

I have checked the link : [How to get first n elements in an array in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355916/how-to-get-first-n-elements-in-an-array-in-hive/25416301#25416301)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT  Seq, col  FROM 
(SELECT  array(  col1, col2 , col3,col4) 
as arr_r FROM srctable ) arrayrec
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(arrayrec.arr_r) EXPLODED_rec as Seq, col;
```

Also check your hive version. posexplode() is available as of Hive 0.13.0.

Comment: I am using Hive 0.12.0. can i use posexplode(), if yes how can i achieve. I tried your suggestion it is not working

Comment: posexplode() is not shipped with hive 0.12.0. Only way you can use posexplode() is compiling it from hive 0.13.0 source as custom UDTF and importing into hive 0.12.0.